# Static website in S3 to access EC2 backend API privately

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a static angular website that I deployed in S3. The website is connecting to a public based ec2 instance that host a spring boot REST API. everything works as BANANA. I wanted to pass this small experience and use AWS backbone network.[faster, and cheaper]. In other words, instead of calling my API through a pubic IP address, where the call goes out to internet then again in to AWS, I wanted rather call my ec2 instance using its **private IP**.
the bucket is in the same region where the ec2 is running.
is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Your explanation is a little unclear.  From where are you wanting to call the EC2 instance? Calls are made from a user's browser, not from Amazon S3. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Hmmm, I absolutely agree. at the end, the angular application is nothing but a JavaScript code that runs in the client browser. so, actually, the request goes from the client browser and not from S3. THANK YOU !!! –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanted rather call my ec2 instance using its private IP

You **can't do this**. S3 bucket website are designed to work over the Internet, not within a VPC which would be required for what you want to do.

You could only front your ec2 instance with a load balancer, and then from your s3 website call the LB over the internet. This still uses the internet, but at least you could have your ec2 instance in a private subnet.

Comment: I absolutely agree. at the end, the angular application is nothing but a JavaScript code that runs in the client browser. so, actually, the request goes from the client browser and not from S3. THANK YOU !!!

Comment: @TarekSahalia No problem. Glad I could help.